# Multi term search not giving results

Tags: elasticsearch

Using elasticsearch 7.1.0 I have objects like this:

```
{
... other fields
"entityId": "abcdef",
"anotherParameter": "something@weird-here"
}
```

I need to make an exact match on both entityId and anotherParameter (case can be ignored).
I use this query via the NEST library in C#

```
GET objects/_search
{
    "from": 0,
    "query": {
        "bool": {
            "filter": [
                {
                    "bool": {
                        "must": [
                            {
                                "term": {
                                    "entityId": {
                                        "value": "abcdef"
                                    }
                                }
                            },
                            {
                                "term": {
                                    "anotherParameter": {
                                        "value": "something@weird-here"
                                    }
                                }
                            }
                        ]
                    }
                }
            ]
        }
    }
}
```

Which does not return anything.
Mappings for both fields is:

```
"type" : "text",
          "fields" : {
            "keyword" : {
              "type" : "keyword",
              "ignore_above" : 256
            }
          }
```

If I leave out the @ and just put in "something" in the anotherParameter field, I get the right objects but also stuff that I don't want returned.
I'm looking for directions on how to do the exact search. Anyone?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> If I leave out the @ and just put in "something" in the
> anotherParameter field, I get the right objects

The [standard analyzer](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/analysis-standard-analyzer.html) is the default analyzer which is used if none is specified. You are getting the document with `something` because the text of `anotherParameter` gets analyzed, and the following tokens are generated.

```
{
  "tokens": [
    {
      "token": "something",
      "start_offset": 0,
      "end_offset": 9,
      "type": "<ALPHANUM>",
      "position": 0
    },
    {
      "token": "weird",
      "start_offset": 10,
      "end_offset": 15,
      "type": "<ALPHANUM>",
      "position": 1
    },
    {
      "token": "here",
      "start_offset": 16,
      "end_offset": 20,
      "type": "<ALPHANUM>",
      "position": 2
    }
  ]
}
```

So to get the exact matches, either you can change the data type of the fields to `keyword` type

```
{
  "mappings": {
    "properties": {
      "entityId": {
        "type": "keyword"
      },
      "anotherParameter": {
        "type": "keyword"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

OR if you have not explicitly defined any mapping, then you can also modify your search query like this. You need to add .keyword to both fields. This uses the `keyword` analyzer instead of the `standard` analyzer (notice the ".keyword" after the fields). Try out this below query -
:

```
{
  "from": 0,
  "query": {
    "bool": {
      "filter": [
        {
          "bool": {
            "must": [
              {
                "term": {
                  "entityId.keyword": {
                    "value": "abcdef"
                  }
                }
              },
              {
                "term": {
                  "anotherParameter.keyword": {
                    "value": "something@weird-here"
                  }
                }
              }
            ]
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

**By using both the above methods you will be able to make exact matches, but the search will also be case sensitive.**

**Adding a working example for an exact match with case insensitive search**

**Index Mapping:**

```
{
  "settings": {
    "analysis": {
      "analyzer": {
        "my_analyzer": {
          "type": "custom",
          "filter": [
            "lowercase"
          ],
          "tokenizer": "keyword"
        }
      }
    }
  },
  "mappings": {
    "properties": {
      "entityId": {
        "type": "text",
        "analyzer": "my_analyzer"
      },
      "anotherParameter": {
        "type": "text",
        "analyzer": "my_analyzer"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

**Search API:**

```
{
  "from": 0,
  "query": {
    "bool": {
      "filter": [
        {
          "bool": {
            "must": [
              {
                "match": {
                  "entityId": "Abcdef"
                }
              },
              {
                "match": {
                  "anotherParameter": "something@weird-here"
                }
              }
            ]
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

**Search Result:**

```
"hits": [
      {
        "_index": "65534220",
        "_type": "_doc",
        "_id": "1",
        "_score": 0.0,
        "_source": {
          "entityId": "abcdef",
          "anotherParameter": "something@weird-here"
        }
      }
    ]
```

Comment: That did the trick! And thanks for adding the case-insensitive example - I actually also needed that :)

Comment: @ThomasVestergaard glad this worked for you :) Thank u for accepting the answer, can you please upvote the answer as well :)